# Tauber's theorem (Abel summable $\implies$ convergent) for $\sum c_n$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty} nc_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation, fourier-analysis

> Prove that if $\sum_n c_n$ is Abel summable to $s$, and $nc_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$, then $\sum_n c_n$ converges to $s$.
>
> Exercise $14(b)$, Chapter $2$, Stein & Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis.

*My work:*

**Attempt $1$**: Since $\sum_n c_n$ is Abel summable to $s$, $A(r) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n r^n$ converges for all $0\le r < 1$ and $\lim_{r\to 1^{-}} A(r) = s$. Fix $0\le r < 1$, and $N\in \mathbb N$ sufficiently large.
$$\begin{align*} \left| \sum_{n=1}^N c_n - s \right| &\le \left|\sum_{n=1}^N c_n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n r^n \right| + \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n r^n - s \right| \\ &= \left|\sum_{n=1}^N c_n(1-r^n) - \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n r^n \right| + \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n r^n - s \right|\\ &\le \sum_{n=1}^N |nc_n||1-r| + \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n r^n \right| + \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n r^n - s \right| \end{align*}$$
By Abel summability, $$\lim_{r\to 1^-} \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n r^n - s \right| = 0$$
Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_1\in \mathbb N$ such that $|nc_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N_1$. So,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N |nc_n||1-r| = \sum_{n=1}^{N_1} |nc_n||1-r| + \sum_{n=N_1 + 1}^N |nc_n||1-r| \\ \le |1-r|\sum_{n=1}^{N_1} |nc_n| + \epsilon|1-r|(N-N_1)| \xrightarrow{r\to 1^-} 0$$
Therefore, we have $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N c_n - s \right|\le \left|\lim_{r\to 1^-} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n r^n \right|$$
which gives $$\limsup_{N\to\infty} \left|\sum_{n=1}^N c_n - s \right|\le \limsup_{N\to\infty} \left|\lim_{r\to 1^-} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n r^n \right|\le \limsup_{N\to\infty}\lim_{r\to 1^-} \sum_{n= N+1}^\infty |c_n|r^n$$
If we can show that $\limsup_{N\to\infty}\lim_{r\to 1^-} \sum_{n= N+1}^\infty |c_n|r^n = 0$, we shall be done.

**Attempt $2$**: The book provides a hint - to consider $r = 1 - \frac1N$. Take $r = 1 - \frac1N$. Then,
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N c_n - s \right|\le \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N_1} |nc_n| + \epsilon\left(1 - \frac{N_1}{N} \right)  + \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n \left( 1 - \frac1N \right)^n \right| + \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \left( 1 - \frac1N \right)^n - s \right|$$
Taking $\limsup_{N\to\infty}$, we get
$$\limsup_{N\to\infty} \left|\sum_{n=1}^N c_n - s \right|\le \epsilon  + \left|\limsup_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n \left( 1 - \frac1N \right)^n \right|$$
If we can show that $\limsup_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n \left( 1 - \frac1N \right)^n = 0$, we'll be done.

Thanks a lot! Any help is appreciated.
I know that this question has been asked on the site before, but I need help with *my attempt* in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've picked $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $n\vert c_n\vert <\epsilon$. This means

$$\begin{align}\left\vert\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}c_n\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{n}\right\vert &\leq  \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\vert c_n\vert\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{n} \\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{N}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{n}\\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{N}\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{N}}{1-(1-\frac{1}{N})}\\
&\leq \epsilon \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^N \leq \frac{\epsilon}{e}\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that I have picked $N_1$ such that $n \ge N_1\implies |nc_n| < \epsilon$, and $N$ is sufficiently large (so $N > N_1$) and your claim in the first line follows. I agree with the rest of your solution. Thanks a lot - this is excellent!

Comment: Just to confirm, $$\limsup_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n \left( 1 - \frac1N \right)^n = 0$$ is also true, right? We just proved that $$\limsup_{N\to\infty} \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty c_n \left( 1 - \frac1N \right)^n \right| \le \epsilon e$$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, from which the equality should follow.

Comment: Yes, this shows this term is smaller than $\epsilon e$ for $N$ sufficiently large. So it is also true for the $\limsup$.

Comment: If am not wrong, you can get a better bound. You can get $\frac{\epsilon}{e}$ instead of $\epsilon e$. Does not affect the solution, but still.

Comment: @delta-divine you are correct, it was a typo that I fixed.